# Can I set a certain script on a file that can access & write to another file but prevent sheet users from browsing or editing this destination file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made two separate google sheet files, 'Order Form sheet' file and 'Order Collect sheet' file.
As you can see on the sheet names, when users input order details into the Order Form sheet and click submit, the script sends the details to the Order Collect sheet.

The sheet works well for me, but I found that the users must have edit access of the destination file. Since there is information that should not be disclosed to other users, I can't grant edit access of the destination file to every user.
Even if I don't open the destination file's URL or ID, a user familiar with google script can find out the destination file's ID because it is written on the script.

Is there any way that the original file can have access to write the destination google sheet file, but each user doesn't have access to the destination file?

I considered the google form, but it won't work because the original file should have the report/summary and email notification function written by google script.

Also setting the general access to public can't be done because of the security reason.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `'Order Form sheet' file` and `'Order Collect sheet' file` and `destination file` and `original file` and `destination google sheet file` and your script. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Tanaike. My apologies for the vague explanation.
"Order Form Sheet = original file" and "Order Collect Sheet = destination file = destination google sheet file"
The basic scheme is to submit order info written from the "Order Form Sheet" to "Order Collect Sheet"
Various users with various "Order Form Sheet" will submit the information to one google sheet file, "Order Collect Sheet"

Comment: Thank you for replying. `Order Form Sheet` and `Order Collect Sheet` are in the same Spreadsheet? I couldn't understand whether your question is about multiple sheets in one Google Spreadsheet or about each single sheet in multiple Google Spreadsheets. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: No problem, actually I appreciate your concern. The answer for your question is no. The `Order Form Sheet` and `Order Collect Sheet` are two different sheets. Each single sheet in multiple Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: In addition, the `Order Form Sheet` is for our clients and the `Order Collect Sheet` is for our staffs. I want clients won't be able to browse or copy the `Order Collect Sheet`. But so far as I know, clients should have access to the `Order Collect Sheet` in order to the script work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my understanding is correct, in your situation, how about editing your `Order Collect Sheet` by Web Apps? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) I think that when Web Apps is used, the users can run your script as the owner of the script (In this case, you are the owner of the script.) even when your Spreadsheet is not shared with users. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result. So, I proposed it as a comment. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This was intended to be more of a comment than an answer, but it got too long, so consider it more of an idea for an alternative approach.

First off, when you grant users the ability to write from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with a script, you are making them editors which also gives them the ability to see the file.  Essentially, by setting it up this way, you are saying on the one hand, "I want users to be able to edit the file", while on the other hand you are saying, "I don't want users to be able to edit or see the file."

One idea is to use a Google Form and then use `onFormSubmit()`.  When the `onFormSubmit()` function is triggered, you can then send notifications and report/summary to the parties concerned.

That is how I would try to go about it.  Maybe this could work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I prefer google spread sheet because there are some google functions used in the `Order Form Sheet`, but I will try the Google Form with the `onFormSubmit()`